# Java: get actual type of generic method with lambda parameter

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I asked some question about `lambdas` here [Java: how to resolve generic type of lambda parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863716), but this one is a bit different.

I have the method signature:

```
public <P> void handle(Consumer<P> consumer) {
...
}
```

I can use it with `lambda`:

```
.<Integer>handle(p -> System.out.println(p * 2));
```

Can I somehow resolve that actual generic type? 
I mean I want to get `Integer.class` within that `handle` method.

BTW I can resolve the issue like this:

```
 public <P> void handle(Class<P> pClass, Consumer<P> consumer) {...}

 .handle(Integer.class, p -> System.out.println(p * 2));
```

But it doesn't look kosher, if we change the lambda to inline implementation.

Comment: No. Otherwise you might close that topic as one with many questions. They provide separete subjects and expect different answers

Comment: I'm not sure I see the difference between the two questions.

Comment: I also don't get it to be honest

Comment: It is possible - you just need to grab a reference to the lambda before passing it into `handle` that way you can resolve the type argument for its class. Ex: `TypeResolver.resolveRawArgument(Consumer.class, lambda.getClass());`. See [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) for more usage info.

Comment: Thanks, @Jonathan, but it doesn't help me. Please, see how end-user code looks using my framework: https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/25/spring-integration-java-dsl-line-by-line-tutorial

Comment: @ArtemBilan - Another option is to do the type resolution from inside your handle method: `TypeResolver.resolveRawArgument(Consumer.class, consumer.getClass());` That should work.

Comment: Great! Thanks, @Jonathan, it works fine! I'll consider to use your solution for the next release

Comment: Glad it worked. Are you planning to add TypeTools as a spring-integration dependency or update spring's internal type resolver to do something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

You cannot get something like `T.class`, because generics are erased at runtime. You really need to pass in `Class<T>` to be able to get the class itself.

I also smell an XY-problem. Perhaps you *really* need the class type, but without further information, this smells a little bit.

Comment: Good. I accepted the answer and go ahead with the solution

Comment: Yes it **is** possible to recreate the value of T since it's captured in the bytecode as part of the lambda's method invocation. See [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) for an example.

Comment: Agree with @Jonathan, you can get the types, they are erased through the usual methods of getting types, however that doesn't mean they are fully erased at runtime, they are still present and can be got through different means, e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/GenericTypeResolver.html