# How to correctly determine that an object is a lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I see that the class of a lambda is `isSynthetic() && !isLocalOrAnonymousClass()`, but I presume that the same may be true for proxy classes.

Of course, I could check that `getDeclaredMethods().length == 1` and apply `regexp` to the class name.

However I want to know if there is a more elegant and robust option to find out if a given object is a lambda.

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you want to match proxy classes?

Comment: Why do you want to know? Just interested in what you're use case is.

Comment: Note that `getDeclaredMethods().length == 1` only holds if the Lambda is not `Serializable`. Then, it will generate a `.writeReplace()` as well.

Comment: Right, I know that. In my case all Lambdas are my own. So, I have a control over them: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-java-dsl

Comment: I found this question because I was making an interface with 2 method overloads: one  taking in a <T extends AutoCloseable> and another Supplier<T extends AutoCloseable>.  Funny enough, lambdas implement AutoCloseable and it would not compile because it could not disambiguate which overload to call if I passed in a Supplier lambda.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is no official way to do this, by design.  Lambdas are part of the language; and are integrated into the type system through functional interfaces.  There should be no need to distinguish a `Runnable` that began life as a lambda, a named class, or an inner class -- they're all Runnables.  If you think you have to "deal with lambda" by taking apart the class file, you're almost certainly doing something wrong!

Comment: Here is a couple of my today's question about issues with Lambdas and generics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863716/java-how-to-resolve-generic-type-of-lambda-parameter, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865950/java-get-actual-type-of-generic-method-with-lambda-parameter. I think they should shed some light what I want to get.

Comment: Those questions suggest that you are not fully on board with how *erasure* works in implementing Java generics.  This has nothing to do with lambda; the same issues show up with named classes.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with you, because we can do so mach with reflection and generics at runtime, that it looks like Java hasn't done enough for lambdas. We often use generic resolution and reflection info at runtime to make many thing flexible and usefull for end-users, e.g. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10675. We resolve it like `GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(listenerType, ApplicationListener.class)`, but since lambda doesn't provide generic info we end up with issue.

Comment: The same here with parameter types and `ConversionService`. Of course you can say that Spring `not fully on board with how erasure works`, but why don't go to meet people and don't implement what we (and others) need?

Comment: To your "I'm not sure I agree with you" response: this is pure wishful thinking.  Yes, there are a few corner cases in which you can get reflection to cough up some compile-time type decisions (specifically with anonymous classes), but these are the exceptions, not the other way around.  Generics are erased; reflection is for reflecting over CLASSES, not INSTANCES.  I can imagine you'd want it to work differently, of course, but you're looking for "how do I" answers, and they're not there.

Comment: @Holger: That technique is pretty dangerous.  Serialized lambdas have significantly higher performance costs compared to nonserializable lambdas, and are less secure (serialization is inherently a public hidden constructor to behavior and/or captured data that the programmer might have intended to stay private.)  This is not a free lunch.

Comment: @BrianGoetz, one related question. Could you explain why function types/literals weren't added to the language? It's much nicer to write a method that takes a function and not to think which functional interface to use. Calling a function with `f()` like in Scala would also be a nice improvement over `f.supply()` or `f.whatever()`

Comment: @damluar Too many reasons to fit in 600 characters!  This is a classic example of one of those ideas that is obvious and yet in hindsight turned out to be the wrong thing to do.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLksirK9nnE for some of the reasons.

Comment: Lambdas do not work the same as anonymous inner classes. They have different scoping rules (lambdas use lexical scoping), they are compiled differently, they are executed differently under the hood, and they interact differently with class initialization (due to the scoping rules).

Comment: I don't know the questioner's motivation, but I have one that I feel is perfectly legitimate. I have a list of listeners, which is a list of WeakReferences to my listeners. This protects me from memory leaks. It sounds great, but it has a problem. If the listener is anonymous or a lambda, it won't have any references to it, so it will immediately get garbage collected. My (less than ideal) solution used to be to reject anonymous listeners, forcing the developer to rewrite the code using a non-anonymous listener. But this fails with lambdas because I have no way to test for them.

Comment: I think one of the reasons this issue comes up is that, in principle, a lambda expression behaves exactly like any other object, so we don't need to know which objects are lambdas. In practice, there are certain situations where lambdas (and anonymous classes) don't behave like other objects, and one of them is garbage collection.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz I'm not following your example.  If I do `registerListener(new FooListener())`, and you wrap it with a `WeakReference`, it will still get garbage collected, because you threw away the last strong reference.

Comment: @Brian Goetz Good question. Let me give you a real-world example. Suppose I have a JComponent that response to an ActionListener. When its enclosing JFrame gets closed, the JComponent no longer needs to respond. But if I fail to remove the listener, I'll get a memory leak. As Joshua Block suggested in Effective Java, my ListenerList can be a list of WeakReferences, so they'll get deleted automatically when the JFrame gets closed. But this fails if I write thing.addListener(new ActionListener() {...}). It also fails if I add new FooListener(), but I don't expect anyone to do this. ...

Comment: ... (Joshua Bloch didn't consider this possibility) I deal with this by rejecting anonymous listeners. My error message references my class's javadocs, which explain that the listener should be directly implemented by the class that the listener responds to. So I'm primarily concerned with the idioms that are actually in use. I'm aware that it's not foolproof.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz OK, so this really has nothing to do with lambdas vs named classes; you have a subtle invariant, that _some other entity_ manages the reachability of the listener. That's a clever trick but it's really just a super-complex precondition that you can't dynamically test, so you have to put it on your caller.  Filtering out anon classes or lambdas would only filter out a subset of the immediately-failing cases.

Comment: @Brian Goetz As I said, my solution is less than ideal. But you're thinking theoretically, while I'm thinking about actual practice. I've written a lot of Swing UIs, and nobody writes listeners like your FooListener, it's too much trouble — every listener is different. They're almost always written as anonymous classes, or lambdas. So that's what I most need to catch. It's not foolproof. I can't catch every incorrect usage, but a test for lambdas would let me catch more of them. It's a small courtesy that I offer to developers. I just wish the Java language offered me the same courtesy.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz It's easy to justify any given "less than ideal" hack to address a perceived need.  But, I invite you to think about what would happen if we added to "Everybody's Java" the union of all the "less than ideal" hacks that all of the 9M Java developers are able tp justify to themselves.  I promise you, that's not the Java you -- or anybody --  wants to program in.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz If you're just optimistically filtering as a proxy for the (impossible to actually detect) actual precondition in the hopes of catching 90% of the bugs, any of the ad-hoc solutions (class name contains `$$Lambda`, class is a VMAC) would work well enough for your purposes.  They may have false positives, but if your goal is just to catch silly errors, seems like you're fine with that.

Comment: @BrianGoetz So you're saying I can just just write a hack. Yeah, I know. I have a bias against hacks. I guess I don't understand why it's okay to have isAnonymous() but not isLambda(). It's precisely this kind of unexpected problem (even Joshua Bloch didn't expect it) that make methods like isLambda() useful. Your original claim was that if I want to do this, I'm doing something wrong. I'm not. I'm catching someone else doing something wrong. Is the hack guaranteed to keep working as the language changes? Maybe it is. I don't know. isLambda() feels safer. I come to this site to avoid hacks.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz What I'm saying is that what you're doing is already unsound and brittle and deeply hacky, and exposing a `isLambda()` method would only make it .1% less so.  So, no, you've not offered any new or legitimate motivation for us to expose such an API point.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Based on my experience, I'm generally distrustful of using reflection. (I could say a lot here.) But where I've found reflection to be useful is in diagnosing problems. That's exactly what I'm doing here, and it's how I've used isAnonymous(). I still don't understand why isAnonymous() is acceptable but isLambda() isn't. My point is in to keep calls to isAnonymous() out of production code. If this is so unsound, then why is isAnonymous() available?

Comment: @MiguelMunoz Questions like this may seem obvious, but are actually pretty unhelpful. They belie a black-and-white view (100% right or 100% wrong), and assume everything that's been done already must be 100% right.  So "if X is OK, Y should be OK" both assumes that the considerations around X and Y are identical (never true), and also that `isAnonymous()` was a 100% great idea. (Some ideas are 51% ideas.)  Neither are valid assumptions. In any case, I don't see the value of continuing here. We made the right call then, and nothing has come to light since that makes me want to change my mind.

Comment: I see it pretty confusing that a lambda class is not considered anonymous. After all, no-one gave it a name. And it is not precisely the same as `Runnable`, of course. It's just a subclass. 
So if a lambda class is not anonymous, how should I access it by name?

Comment: @AhmadShahwan What you're getting confused over is the term "anonymous class" already has a meaning in Java, and a lambda is not that, despite many people thinking they are the same thing.  Yes, it is "anonymous" in the english sense that it has no name.  But when a Java developer says "anonymous class", they mean way more than that; similarly the reflective call `isAnonymous()` refers to more than just the english meaning.

Comment: There is at least one case where it matters: memory measurement. Tactically, there are issues with JAMM because Java errors are thrown when trying to measure objects that contain lambdas. It's also questionable whether one should count lambdas as part of the object size because they're part of the compiled code.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to check if a `Runnable` - or any other functional interface - has been implemented by a Lambda is to check if the class is synthetic but the interface's function isn't:

```java
Class clz = suspectedObject.getClass();
var isLambda = clz.isSynthetic() && !clz.getDeclaredMethod("run").isSynthetic();
```

Note that this will also detect function references (`this::run`) - I don't think there's a way to distinguish between that form and an anonymous lambda.

I want to use this method to log the type of the object in a nicer way - my framework sometime logs the names of provided interface implementations to let the user know in which part of their code they have a problem, and lambda's `toString()` is next to useless. Not that I've yet figured out what is a useful way to represent the notion of "you should look at this specific lambda and not any of the other dozens of lambdas in your class".

Answer (score 0):

If you know the lambda extends `Serializable` you could check the synthetic `writeReplace` method that is generated returns a `SerializedLambda` as shown below.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class IsLambdaExample
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println(
            "Is anonymous inner class a lambda: "+isLambda(
                new SerialisableFunction<Object,Object>(){ public Object apply( Object o ){ return null; } }
            )
        );
        System.out.println( "Is lambda a lambda: "+isLambda( (SerialisableFunction<Object,Object>)o -> null ) );
        System.out.println(
            "Is proxy instance a lambda: "+isLambda(
                (SerialisableFunction)Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(),
                    new Class[]{ SerialisableFunction.class },
                    new InvocationHandler()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public Object invoke( Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args )
                        {
                            return null;
                        }

                        private SerializedLambda writeReplace()
                        {
                            return new SerializedLambda( InvocationHandler.class, "", "", "", 0, "", "", "", "", new Object[]{} );
                        }
                    }
                )
            )
        );
    }

    public static <T extends Function<?,?> & Serializable> Boolean isLambda( T potentialLambda )
    {
        try{
            Class<?> potentialLambdaClass = potentialLambda.getClass();
            if( !potentialLambdaClass.isSynthetic() ){
                return false;
            }
            Method writeReplace = potentialLambdaClass.getDeclaredMethod("writeReplace");
            writeReplace.setAccessible(true);
            Object writeReplaceObject = writeReplace.invoke(potentialLambda);
            return writeReplaceObject != null && SerializedLambda.class.isAssignableFrom( writeReplaceObject.getClass() );
        }
        catch( NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException ignored ){
            return false;
        }
    }

    interface SerialisableFunction<T,U> extends Function<T,U>, Serializable {}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public static boolean isLambda(Object obj) {
    return obj.getClass().toString().contains("$$Lambda$");
}
```

Comment: No, this does not appear valid.

Comment: It won't work because nothing can stop me from naming my class "My$$Lambda$1" for example :-)

Comment: I would replace toString() with getSimpleName(). It shortens the search for $$Lambda$.