# Can you inspect the byte code of a Java 8 lambda at runtime?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, bytecode

If you have an anonymous class like

```
Predicate<String> isEmpty = new Predicate<String>() {
    public boolean test(String t) {
        return t.isEmpty();
    }
};
```

A library which is passed the reference to `isEmpty` can inspect the byte code to see what it does and possibly manipulate it.  Is there a way you can do this for lambdas?

```
Predicate<String> isEmpty = String::isEmpty;
```

e.g Say have this code and byte code

```
public class Main {
    public static void test(Predicate<String> tester) {
        System.out.println("tester.getClass()= " + tester.getClass());
        System.out.println("tester.getClass().getClassLoader()="+ tester.getClass().getClassLoader());
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Predicate<String> isEmpty = String::isEmpty;
        test(isEmpty);
    }
}

$ javap -cp . -c -private Main.class
Compiled from "Main.java"
public class Main {
  public Main();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void test(java.util.function.Predicate<java.lang.String>);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       6: dup           
       7: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      10: ldc           #5                  // String tester.getClass()= 
      12: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      15: aload_0       
      16: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
      19: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      22: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      25: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      28: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      31: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      34: dup           
      35: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      38: ldc           #11                 // String tester.getClass().getClassLoader()=
      40: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      43: aload_0       
      44: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
      47: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/lang/Class.getClassLoader:()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
      50: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      53: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      56: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      59: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    Code:
       0: invokedynamic #13,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:test:()Ljava/util/function/Predicate;
       5: astore_1      
       6: aload_1       
       7: invokestatic  #14                 // Method test:(Ljava/util/function/Predicate;)V
      10: return        
}
```

With a reference to `tester` in `test` how do I find which method is called?

Comment: With a method reference, you can see which method is referenced and then go find that method's byte code. With a regular old lambda, the lambda byte code should be in a `lambda$#` private method. Just `javap` with `-private` option.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for as an answer? The bytecode does contain entries for both lambdas and method references, so, yes, you can inspect the byte code. Are you asking how?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes. Say I have the example above.  I have a reference to isEmpty.  How to do I find the code this instance will call?

Comment: It appears that the BootstrapMethods might hold the key.  Is this the case/best way to do this?

Comment: I do believe this is the way to do it. A library like ASM should be able to determine/interpret bootstrap methods, but I don't know the _how_ exactly.

Comment: Poor bounty... I appreciate the guesture, though ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to SEE the bytecode:

```
javap -c -p -v classfile
      ^disassemble
         ^private methods
            ^verbose, including constant pool and bootstrap methods attribute
```

But if you want to try to do this at runtime, you're pretty much out of luck (by design, we don't have anything like Expression Trees), as the other answer suggests.

Comment: +1 Do you know of any plans to change the option `jdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses` ?  Since it is "internal" I can expect it to change at any time, but some idea of what that might be would be helpful.

Comment: Of course, Brian is correct, no public API is provided to do this, but that doesn't mean it's impossible, https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools does some tricky stuff to load the constant pool and find the referenced method. The code to do it though is somewhat fragile, I think u60 broke it, for example.

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is: You can't. There is a [related answer of Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870478/how-to-correctly-determine-that-an-object-is-a-lambda/23870800#23870800) on this matter. For implementing lambda expressions, *javac* creates an `INVOKEDYNAMIC` instruction which delegates the invocation to the [`LambdaMetafactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html)'s bootstrap method. For the OpenJDK, this bootstrap method is then creating an implementation of the required interface at runtime using [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).

Within the `test` method, the retreived instance `tester` is of this ASM-generated class such that you have no class file to read for finding out which method the `Predicate` represents. In the general case, the exact decision of how to map lambda expressions to interface implementations is left to the runtime environment what makes your problem even harder. The only way to find out which method a lambda expression represents is to read the byte code of its creation, i.e. interpreting the `main` method, for your example.

Answer (score 3):

After all, I found a way of getting hold of a lambda expression's class file that is rather reliable (but of course still relies on implementation details.) For an experimental implementation, I am now using a [Java agent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) which allows for the *retransformation* of classes but which is itself implemented as a no-op, I am only interested in the binary array that is handed as an argument.

After getting hold of an `Instrumentation` instance via the registered Java agent, one registers a `ClassFileTransformer` which is then notified over the binary representation once one *retransforms* `lambdaInstance.getClass()`. This is of course a rather hacky solution and might break once the internal implementation of lambdas is changed in the future.

Unfortunately, I did not find any documentation on how an agent is supposed to behave with class retransformation of a lambda expression's synthetic class on a standards-compatible JVM.

Comment: AFAIK, the lack of documentation has been solved—by not calling class file transformers for lambda classes anymore…

Comment: That is correct. This holds for all classes that were defined by an anonymous class loader.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way: by patching the `InnerClassLambdaMetafactory` it is possible to add an annotation to the lambda classes which points to the implementation method. This is possible at runtime by loading an agent and retransforming the metafactory. See [my Blog](http://ruediste.github.io/bytecode/2017/02/25/lambda-inspection.html) for details.