# Build ClassReader from anonymous class created by Unsafe

Tags: java, classloader, anonymous-class, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I tried to build a ASM ClassReader from an anonymous Class, but fails.

The Anonymous class is created by:

```
         Class cls = Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Hoster, byte[], null);
```

The cls.getName() is`class code.jit.asm.example.Callee/629106582` which is somewhat different from tradtion name we see: `class code.jit.asm.example.Callee`

Then I tried:

```
a)  ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(cls.getName())

b)  public static InputStream getClassInputStream(Class cls){
        String classAsPath = cls.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
        return cls.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(classAsPath);
        //return cls.getResourceAsStream(classAsPath);
    }
    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(getClassInputStream(cls))
```

Both a) and b） raise the same exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Class not found
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:455)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:
```

How can I ontain the inputstream of an anonymous Class?

Comment: It's good to use the [tag:java] tag on Java questions.

Comment: "/"  is not ([egal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) for classname.  How did you create it?

Comment: @Jayan, it is created by Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(..)

Comment: Looks like a design [decision]. (http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/Lambda-class-names-no-longer-reported-when-listening-for-JVMTI-EVENT-CLASS-FILE-LOAD-events-td174840.html).  More [at](https://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/anonymous_classes_in_the_vm).  [Unsafe source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java)

Answer (score 0):

ASM cannpt read the class file as the code you are trying to locate is not provided by a class loader where ASM normally reads the class file from. You can however access the byte code using a Java agent as I explained in this answer: [Can you inspect the byte code of a Java 8 lambda at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579276/can-you-inspect-the-byte-code-of-a-java-8-lambda-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

The term *anonymous* class should point you to it. You can’t access *anonymous* classes by name as that’s the point of being *anonymous*. Anonymous classes are not referenced by a `ClassLoader` so unlike ordinary classes they may get garbage collected when they are not in use any more.

If you want to get hands on the classes generated for lambda expressions, you may use the option
`-Djdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses=targetdirectory`.

Generally, the JRE uses this feature for implementing the lambda expression/method reference instances and for `MethodHandle`’s. In both cases, the generated classes have such a simple structure that it is not really interesting to look at them…