# How can I safely proxy a lambda when I don't know whether it's a lambda up-front?

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, java-8, cglib

We have some legacy reflected proxy generation code which basically works like this if you look at it as a black box:

```
Object someObject = new Anything();
Object debugObject = ProxyUtils.wrapWithDebugLogging(someObject);
```

wrapWithDebugLogging takes any object and overrides any method it *can* (final methods are obviously unfixable if you're extending a real class), intercepting it to log a message about the call, then calling the real method.

Inside, it's using cglib to do the work and has a bit of protective logic before it constructs the proxy, because anonymous classes are final, yet can be handled by using the superclass or single interface they implement:

```
Class<?> clazz = someObject.getClass();
Class<?> interfaces = clazz.getInterfaces();

// Anonymous classes are final so you can't extend them, but we know they only have one
// superclass or one interface.
if (clazz.isAnonymousClass()) {
    clazz = interfaces.length > 0 ?
            interfaces[0] : primaryType.getSuperclass();
}

Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();

if (clazz.isInterface()) {
    interfaces.add(clazz);
} else {
    enhancer.setSuperclass(primaryType);
}
enhancer.setInterfaces(interfaces.toArray(new Class[interfaces.size()]));
```

The problem is that Java 8's "lambda" classes return false for isAnonymousClass(). But we would like to treat them exactly the same as the anonymous class.

It has been [pointed out before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870478/how-to-correctly-determine-that-an-object-is-a-lambda) that there is no way to determine that a class is a lambda class "by design". But this just seems more like something lacking in the reflection API to me and it certainly isn't the first time Java has "forgotten" to add something obvious to a new API.

So is there a sensible way to distinguish a lambda from a non-lambda without having this feature in the API? I can see that isSynthetic() returns true, but it also returns true for all kinds of other things, presumably.

Comment: Why don't you check if the `Class` is `final` with `Modifier.isFinal(..)`?

Comment: If we used this trick for all final classes, you can hit a final class which has final methods which defined on the final class itself. In this situation, that method would not be implemented by the proxy, so if someone called it, you would get a NoSuchMethodError. For this reason, we're being conservative about which final classes we let through. Maybe this means we should just check for final classes where all the methods exist on the superclass or one of the interfaces. I'm not really sure if that's a good heuristic or not.

Comment: No, it was not "forgotten".  It was deliberately left out because it would violate the language's abstractions.

Comment: @BrianGoetz And leaving it out violates the reflection API. So you win some, you lose some.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. You can’t subclass *any* `final` class, so it’s pointless to ask whether the `final` class has `final` methods or not. You can’t override any of them. On the other hand, when subclassing the superclass or implementing the interface(s) of the `final` class, you can redeclare methods regardless of whether the then-unrelated `final` class declares them as `final`. If you stick to your logic, it’s easy to construct examples that are neither anonymous nor lambdas bud still break your code.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn’t create conditional code depending on the question whether a class was generated for a lambda or not. After all, only the *properties* of the class matter.

The class is `final` so yo can’t subclass it. Even if it wasn’t `final`, subclasses weren’t possible due to the fact that it has only `private` constructors. And it implements an `interface`. These are the relevant properties of the class.

It’s not unrealistic to encounter the same scenario without any lambda expressions:

```
final class NotALambda implements Function<String,String> {

    public static final Function<String,String> INSTANCE=new NotALambda();

    private NotALambda() {}

    public String apply(String t) {
        return t.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Why do you want to treat this class different from a class generated via
`Function<String,String> f=String::toLowerCase;`? It has the same properties and the same obstacles for creating a proxy. And in the comments you said you want to make a difference based on the question whether the method is declared `final` or not. This makes even lesser sense as I could add a `final` modifier to the method in the above example without changing anything, neither the semantic nor the difficulties you will face when creating a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this limitation (if you want to call it that) should be an issue.

If you're properly programming to interfaces where appropriate, making your proxy have a superclass (other than `Object`) becomes unnecessary. Set the proxy's superclass when it is available (no `private` constructor, not `final`, etc.).

In all cases, all you need to do is capture the proxied object, the target, intercept all method invocations on it, do your logging, and then delegate or route the invocation to it.

```
public static Object wrapWithDebugLogging(Object target) {
    ... // prepare the enhancer as described above
    enhancer.setCallback(new MethodInterceptor() {        
        @Override
        public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
            logger.debug("Some useful logging message.");
            return method.invoke(target, args);            
        }
    });
    return enhancer.create();
}
```

It doesn't matter if the method invoked was `final`, you're not trying to override it, you're just intercepting it.

Comment: Many third party libraries (or in many cases even the Java runtime itself) are not programming to interfaces. I realise that in all cases, we could just introduce an interface which has all methods and then write a delegate to pass the calls through, but if we wanted to write a new interface and delegating implementation class every time we just wanted to debug some method calls, we would just write one more implementation of that interface which does the debug logging. The point of doing this as a proxy is that you write the logic once and once only.

Comment: Plus, if we only had to deal with interfaces, we wouldn't be using cglib. Because it is actually slower than using java.lang.reflect.Proxy. :(

Comment: @Trejkaz Sure. When a superclass is available, use it. The class of an instance created from a lambda expression is `final`. Treat it like any other `final` class.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the results of a quick experiment.  The `foo` method just outputs `getClass().toString()` of its argument.  (`getClass().getName()` outputs the same results.)

```
    foo (new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("run");
            }
         });
```

output: `Test32$1`

```
    foo (() -> System.out.println("run"));
```

output: `Test32$$Lambda$1/640070680`

No guarantees about how portable this is.

Comment: That output can change in the future or by compiler or JVM implementation. Don't rely on it.

Comment: I thought about the toString() hack as well but a future version of the JRE could break it. Then again, a future version of the JRE broke isAnonymousClass() as well, so who knows what is safe anyway...

Comment: @Trejkaz Right, I thought that lambdas were shorthands for anonymous classes, so I was rather surprised to find that `isAnonymousClass` returned `false`.

Comment: @ajb and Trejkaz -- Lambdas are not shorthand for anonymous classes.  Their semantics and representation are different.

Comment: @ajb I learned a long time ago that they weren't. I learned only recently that Oracle don't think we should be able to tell what they are.

Comment: It's a very simple story: they are instances of a functional interface.  How that instance was created -- by instantiating a named class, an anonymous class, a dynamic proxy, a lambda expression, a cloud of pixy dust -- is (and should be!) hidden behind the abstraction of "interface".

Comment: @BrianGoetz exactly. There are so many things it could have been implemented with, that it would have been _really_ convenient to have a single isLambda() method which could have caught all these cases in a single shot instead of having to write weird heuristics to try and match the class based on its characteristics... Even if some class slipped through the net (e.g. the non-anonymous final class in the other answer), we can avoid writing that, but we can't very easily avoid writing lambdas, because they're so damn convenient. :)