# Original FQDN of anonymous class

Tags: java, reflection, anonymous-class

I want to store properties in a `Map` by their class, i.e. the map should contain only one object of any runtime type. There already is a current implementation (it is an existing project), and the mechanism is implemented with a `Map<String, Object>`.

Current implementation:

```
import com.foo.IConfiguration;
public class ClientCode {
    private Options options = new Options();
    public void putMethod() {
        options.subOptions(new IConfiguration() {
            public void configure() {}
        });
    }

    public Object getMethod() {
        return options.getSubOption(IConfiguration.class);
    }
}
public class Options {
    private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void subOptions(Object subOptionsValue) {
        if (subOptionsValue != null) {
            map.put(subOptionsValue.getClass().getName(), subOptionsValue);
        }
    }
    public Object getSubOption(Class<?> subOptionsClass) {
        return subOptionsClass == null ? null : map.get(subOptionsClass.getName());
    }
}
```

However, this does not work as I want to for anonymous classes. In this case, `getName()` and related methods will put `Options$1` or something similar, while I need it to put `com.foo.IConfiguration` so that I can use it reliably in my getMethod().

I have looked through the API for `java.lang.Class`, but I can't find anything that will point me back to the definition of `com.foo.IConfiguration`. Well, I can, but it's not foolproof: `clazz.getInterfaces()` gives an array of interfaces, which is good here, but I can also create a `new Object() {}` or a local class, or a regular public class.

So is there a decent way to retrieve unambiguously the FQDN of the interface or superclass of an anonymous class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous classes have no fully qualified names you can rely on but you can check whether an object is an anonymous class via `ob.getClass().isAnonymousClass()`. You can then retrieve the superclass or a superinterface only if that returns true.

You should also at least think about handling lambdas, even if you aren't going to run this on Java 8 yet.

Comment: This was start of my solution which seems to work. I'll post the code in a separate answer, but this is what got me thinking.

Answer (score 1):

As promised in the comment to biziclop's suggestion, I'm submitting the code that I put into use. This seems to work for both regular and anonymous classes, whether they implement an interface or extend a superclass.

```
public void subOptions(Object subOptionsValue) {
    if (subOptionsValue != null) {
        Class<?> clazz = subOptionsValue.getClass();
        String clazzName;
        if (clazz.isAnonymousClass()) {
            // not sure if getInterfaces can return null
            if (clazz.getInterfaces() != null && clazz.getInterfaces().length > 0) {
                // anonymous classes can implement only one interface
                clazzName = clazz.getInterfaces()[0].getName();
            } else {
                clazzName = clazz.getSuperclass().getName();
            }
        } else {
            clazzName = clazz.getName();
        }
        map.put(clazzName, subOptionsValue);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Handling lambdas is tougher because there's no unambiguous way to single out lambda implementations, but we can get close enough (for my purposes at least) by following [How to correctly determine that an object is a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23870478/2065017) and changing

```
if (clazz.isAnonymousClass()) {...}
```

to

```
if (clazz.isAnonymousClass() || clazz.isSynthetic()) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put object in map several time by all of its interfaces, and base classes, and super interfaces of its interfaces and so on.

For example you have

```
interface I1 {}
interface I2 extends I1 {}
class C1 {}
class C2 extends C1 implements I2{}
```

And you put instance of your `C2` into `Options`

You may want to retrieve it by `I1.class` or `C1.class`

But in this case you need to be ready for possible ambiguity if you have for example two classes that implement one interface.

For such case you may want to have ability to explicitly specify list of classes and interfaces that may be used to retrieve specific class.

Comment: Sorry, we can't have that kind of ambiguity.

Comment: If you cant then just add everything to the map.