# How to create MessageSelector filter in Spring Integration Java DSL?

Tags: java, spring, lambda, spring-integration, dsl

I tried to create a message filter via lambda expression to filter messages on a base of header value evaluation

```
IntegrationFlows.from(inputChannel())
    .filter((Message<?> m) -> { return m.getHeaders().get(...)...; })
    .transform(...)
    .channel(outputChannel())
    .get();
```

but got exception

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.<...skipped...>.BusinessPayloadData cannot be cast to org.springframework.messaging.Message`

Only this definition works for me

```
IntegrationFlows.from(inputChannel())
    .filter(new MessageSelector(){
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Message<?>message){
            return ...;
        }
    })
    .transform(...)
    .channel(outputChannel())
    .get();
```

Is it possible to create `MessageSelector` instance via lambda expression?

Comment: You are assuming that the Lambda's type is the same as the anonymous class, but it might not be what you think.  A technique I use often when I have problems like this is to use my IDE's refactoring tools to extract the lambda into a separate variable, and see what type is assigned to it in the variable declaration.  If it is different than what I expect, I modify the type and then use the IDE's refactoring tools to inline the lambda back into the original expression.  I find that it will fill in type casts and additional generic type classifiers that I wouldn't have known to add.

Comment: @HankD sure. I do like you say too. But here is more complex case cause of specific `filter` implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
.filter(Message.class, m -> m.getHeaders().get(...)...)
```

There is one more overloaded method to infer the object type for the target method invocation.

See `LambdaMessageProcessor` source code. Since we can't infer the argument type from the Lambda directly [Java: get actual type of generic method with lambda parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865950/java-get-actual-type-of-generic-method-with-lambda-parameter), we have to do that like with one more top level type parameter.

Otherwise it ends up only like `Object`, which the target method invocation treats like a type for the `payload`.