# Wicket LambdaModel and NumberTextField cannot resolveType

Tags: wicket, wicket-8

After switching to `LambdaModel` as an alternative to `PropertyModel` in one of my forms in my Wicket 8 application I have failing submit tests stating:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.math.BigDecimal

My Form Panel has a `NumberTextField` which in my **working** scenario is bound to a `PropertyModel`.

**THIS WORKS**

```
form.add(new NumberTextField<BigDecimal>("myBigDecimalField", new PropertyModel<>(getModel(), "myBigDecimalField")));
```

**THIS DOES NOT WORK**

```
form.add(new NumberTextField<BigDecimal>("myBigDecimalField", LambdaModel.of(getModel(), MyClass::getMyBigDecimalField, MyClass::setMyBigDecimalField)));
```

The problem is that `LambdaModel` does not implement `IObjectClassAwareModel` as `PropertyModel` does and so when the `NumberTextField` tries to resolve the type in `AbstractTextComponent#152` and subsequentially checks in `getModelType` if the model is an instance of  `IObjectClassAwareModel` it will not work, as `LambdaModel` does not implement this interface.

Is this intended that `LamdaModel` does not implmement `IObjectClassAwareModel`.
BTW I know that I can fix this issue with explicitly declaring the type class of the `NumberTextField`.

Comment: IIRC `PropertyModel` uses reflection to determine the types of the properties (using the `PropertyResolver`), which is messy. I guess to keep `LamdbaModel` clean the devs decided against it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regretfully it's quite hard to retrieve any type information from lambdas.

See here for an explanation:

[Java: how to resolve generic type of lambda parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863716/java-how-to-resolve-generic-type-of-lambda-parameter)

So for now it's recommended to pass the type to the component.