# How do i get the generic parameters of an anonymous class?

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface called Listener:

```java
public interface Listener<T> {
    void listen(T t);
}
```

Afterwards, i create some anonymous instances of this listener and add them to a list, like

```java
EventManager.registerListener((Listener<PacketSendEvent>) packetSendEvent ->
        System.out.println("Packet has been sent: " + packetSendEvent.getPacket().getClass().getSimpleName()));
```

and registerListener simply adds them to my list.

Later in the program, i iterate throug this list and get the generic parameters names of these listeners. In the case of the listener shown above, this should be "PacketSendEvent":

```java
listeners.forEach(listener -> {
    String[] split = listener.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0].getTypeName().split("\\.");
    String className = split[split.length - 1];
    className = className.substring(0, className.length() - 1);
    System.out.println("Loaded listener " + listener.getClass().getName() + " which listens to " + className);
});
```

For listeners where i create a normal class this works as it should and prints the generic parameter's class name, but for my anonymous instances it doest **not** work.

**What i figured out:**

For every normal class that implements Listener, the method  `listener.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()` returns the generic interfaces. But for my anonymous class it does not return my generic interfaces, it returns the same as `listener.getClass().getInterfaces()`.

I really dont know how i should fix this, probably some of you know the solution. I appreciate every help i can get.

Kind regards
Luca

Comment: Same as or similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/21887358 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/27550314. Also note that in your code you are not using [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) but lambda expressions.