# Java streams equivalent of C# linq property name?

Tags: java, c#, lambda, properties, method-reference

In C# we can obtain a property, field or method name in runtime, like below:

```
Condition<UserEntity, bool>(v => v.Locked);
```

where `Locked` is one of `UserEntity` properties and `v=>v.Locked` will be sent to a method and finally we can get name of property as string `"Locked"`.

below is `Condition` signature:

```cs
public void Condition<EntityT, ObjectT>(
    Expression<Func<EntityT, object>> propertyExpression
)
```

Method to obtain property name is:

```cs
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(this Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpression = null;
    if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert) {
        var body = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
        memberExpression = body.Operand as MemberExpression;
    } else if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess) {
        memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    }
    if (memberExpression == null) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Not a member access", "member");
    }
    string text = memberExpression.ToString();
    return text.Substring(text.IndexOf('.') + 1);
}
```

Is there any way o obtain field or method names like above but in **Java**?

**Edit**

I developed below method, but this method works somewhere and does not work somewhere, so this is not final answer, if anyone can help me fix problems with this method

```java
public interface SerializableConsumer<THolder> extends Consumer<THolder>, Serializable {}

 * detects and returns name of back field from getter method
 * @param getter getter method to start finding backfield name
 * @return name of backfield
 */
public static String getterFieldName(SerializableConsumer<?> getter) {
    for (Class<?> cl = getter.getClass(); cl != null; cl = cl.getSuperclass()) {
        try {
            Method writeReplaceMethod = cl.getDeclaredMethod("writeReplace");
            writeReplaceMethod.setAccessible(true);
            Object replacement = writeReplaceMethod.invoke(getter);
            if(!(replacement instanceof SerializedLambda))
                break;// custom interface implementation
            SerializedLambda serializedLambda = (SerializedLambda) replacement;
            String getterName = serializedLambda.getImplMethodName();
            if(!getterName.startsWith("get"))
                throw new RuntimeException("getter name must start with 'get'");
            String rawFieldName = getterName.substring("get".length());
            String firstChar = rawFieldName.substring(0, 1);
            String wordRest = rawFieldName.substring(1);
            String fieldName = firstChar.toLowerCase() + wordRest;
            return fieldName;
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {}
        catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Can not find field");
}
```

Comment: In Java, when we want the string `"Locked"`, we use `"Locked"`. Seriously, when you request a function mapping from `UserEntity` to `boolean`, be it `Predicate<UserEntity>` or `Function<UserEntity,Boolean>` or whatever functional interface you like, there is no requirement that the implementation is a named property. It can be an ordinary class, an anonymous class, a proxy, a method reference or a lambda expression. Only one of them directly maps to a named entity, all others may contain arbitrary code.

Comment: Related: [Printing debug info on errors with java 8 lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21860875/2711488), [How to get the MethodInfo of a Java 8 method reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19845213/2711488), [Reflection type inference on Java 8 Lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21887358/2711488)…

Comment: @Holger, question you mentioned helped me, I think you got my mean, I need to get a method name that throws error during compile if it does not exists.